# A value of type 'ThemeData' can't be returned from method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code as below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.yellow);
  }
}
```

I get this error

> A value of type 'ThemeData' can't be returned from method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'

I have tried for a while like changing the `return` type of `build` and putting it to another type for example `dynamic` but it doesn't work as it only expects `Widget`

So what can I do if I want to split my `ThemeData` to another file? Any ideas? You're very welcome to post your own solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly determined, `ThemeData` isn't a `Widget` at all.  If you're trying to create a `ThemeData` to plug into the `theme` parameter of your `MaterialApp` or similar, you can just make a top-level variable:

```
final myAppTheme = ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.yellow);

  // somewhere else
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: myAppTheme,
    // ...
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant return ThemeData because it is not a widget so it cant be rendered on-screen that why flutter giving you this error. Use ThemeData like this

```
MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the default brightness and colors.
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
    accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],

    // Define the default font family.
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',

    // Define the default TextTheme. Use this to specify the default
    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
    ),
  )
);
```